# sql select values with fraction of value equals 9999

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres 9.6 indexed timestamp column with microseconds. The date in the column is pretty random. I need to select only records that have the very last microsecond .9999 in any second in a given period (let's say between '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-02 00:00:00').

Source example:

```
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:00.0312
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:00.9431
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:02.0000
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:03.9999
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:04.9999
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:05.0793
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:05.8356
```

Required SQL output:

```
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:03.9999
mydata, 2017-05-01 00:00:04.9999
```

Table is huge (dozens of millions of records), so performance is a essential.

I also might be a need to find records with '0000' like '2017-05-01 00:00:02.0000', so query need to be flexible enough to delivery '0000' instead of '9999' with minor query modifications.

I have no idea how to solve it and ask for your help.

Comment: if you have index - just the exact value?.. what exactly you cant do?..

Comment: Table obviously has other values. However I need the whole row (consider SELECT * FROM thetable ) matching respective timestamp. I will update expected output in the question.

Comment: so why not `SELECT * FROM thetable where ts > '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and ts < '2017-05-02 00:00:00'` ?..

Comment: Because I need all records that are ENDING .9999 within the range... not just the range with all  values...

Comment: then smth like `with lim as (SELECT * FROM thetable where ts > '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and ts < '2017-05-02 00:00:00') select * from lim where right(ts,4) = '9999'`

Comment: Thanks Vao, but it generates and ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: ...7-05-01 00:00:00' and ts < '2017-05-02 00:00:00') select * f...

Comment: Why not just search for LIKE 9999? It is not possible in other timestamps except milliseconds in your given example.

Comment: @uzla - dont see how you get that error :) please give structure to reproduce

Comment: it is TIMESTAMP as mentioned above... not a STRING.  LIKE does not work for TIMESTAMP and generates  an error.

Comment: @uzla cast to text?.. I gave en axample in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right - you want smth like:

```
t=# create table thetable(d text,ts timestamp);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy thetable from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> a|2017-05-01 00:00:01
>> b| 2017-05-01 00:00:00.9999
>> \.
COPY 2
Time: 33896.222 ms
t=# with lim as (SELECT * FROM thetable where ts > '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and ts < '2017-05-02 00:00:00') select * from lim where right(ts::text,4) = '9999';
 d |            ts
---+--------------------------
 b | 2017-05-01 00:00:00.9999
(1 row)
```

Comment: THIS WORKS! Thanks a lot!

Comment: my pleasure, glad I guessed :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can search like as

```
declare @i varchar(100)
select @i= time from  (
select convert (time,getdate(),114) as  time
)as p

select @i where SUBSTRING(@i,10,4)='9999'
```

i just want to say that you can search time by this.

Comment: Thanks, but it DOES NOT answer the question, because it does not return mydata at all, and instead of Timestamp, the table in this answer is a string... :-( The answer from Vao Tsun has similar approach, however he gives full, correct and working answer to the question.